# Set select2 value via local storage (or any variable)

Tags: jquery, local-storage, jquery-select2

I have a select2 that I may have a local storage variable that I want to use as the selected value for select2 if it's available.

I can't seem to set it though.

```
$ ->
      $('.this-two-different-selects').select2
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
        placeholder: "Saved Search"


      local_var = localStorage.getItem("local_var")
      $('.this-two-different-selects option:contains('+local_var+')').prop("selected", "selected") if local_var
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me using jQuery, Select2 and javascript. It uses an on change event to set the store and get the storage when the page is loaded. 
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/cnxz8pye/16

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var selval = localStorage.getItem("select2Value");
             if(selval){
                $("#sel2").val(selval);
            }
            $("#sel2").select2();
            $("#sel2").on("change", function (evt) {
                var selval = $(evt.target).val();
                localStorage.setItem("select2Value", selval);
            })

    })
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <select id="sel2">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
    </select>

</div>
```